# If you flip 100 coins, what is the probability that between 40 and 60 of them (inclusively) land on heads?

Tags: r

If you flip 100 coins, what is the probability that between 40 and 60 of them
(inclusively) land on heads?

```
Problem <- function()
{
  X<- sample(c('H','T'),100,replace = T)
  X
 }

mean(replicate(10000,sum(ProblemTwo()=='H')==50|60 ))
```

This always return 1
I am not sure what is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are checking the `mean` of those `between` 50 and 60, then use `>=/<=` with `&` operator

```
r1 <- replicate(10000,sum(Problem()=='H'))
mean(r1 >= 50 & r1 <=60)
[1] 0.5214
```

---

The way in which `50|60` is parsed is different i.e. it always returns `TRUE` unless both the values are 0

```
> 50|60
[1] TRUE
> 0|0
[1] FALSE
> 1|0
[1] TRUE
```

i.e. to understand the issue, split the code and check the output

```
> replicate(10,sum(Problem()=='H'))
 [1] 57 50 43 44 43 48 40 37 47 52
```

this gives the `sum` of 'H' from a sample of 100 for each of the 10 replications.  As `50|60` always returns TRUE. Here, in addition to the `|` property the operator precedence also plays a part

```
> sum(Problem()=='H') == 50|60
[1] TRUE
> set.seed(24)
> sum(Problem()=='H') == (50|60)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

## pbinom

Another approach using the binomial distribution.

#### Probability: X <= 60

```
p_60 <- pbinom(60, size = 100, prob = .5, lower.tail=TRUE)
[1] 0.9823999
```

#### Probability: X <= 39

```
p_39 <- pbinom(39, size = 100, prob = .5, lower.tail=TRUE)
[1] 0.0176001
```

#### Probability: 40 <= X <= 60

```
p_60-p_39

[1] 0.9647998
```

## rbinom

```
n <- 100000000

rbinom(n, size = 100, prob = .5) %>%
  cut(c(0,39,60,100)) %>%
  table() %>% 
  .[2]/n

  (39,60] 
0.9647775
```

## replicate

```
problem <- function(n = 100){
  x <- sample(c("H","T"),size = n,replace = TRUE)
  out <- sum(x == "H")
  return(out)
}

n <- 100000    

replicate(n,problem()) %>% 
  cut(c(0,39,60,100)) %>%
  table() %>% 
  .[2]/n

(39,60] 
0.96483
```

Comment: your answer is right but i am not allowed to use pbinom().

Comment: Ok, @Abdulrazzaq updated my answer